# Let bootstrap table go outside bootstrap container?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap container and a boostrap table like this

```
<div class="container">
<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I want to keep my container and no line breaks in my table. If I get one long row in my table it goes under my container (content to the right is hidden in my table). How can I make my table overlap my container to the right if there is lot of content in the table?

Answer (score 1):

It's kinda hard to help without the CSS but based off what I know, I'd try setting `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: If i do that it goes under the div container. No css more than bootstrap.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or something? It's a lot to ask for people to just be able to know the bootstrap styles. Anyone with CSS/HTML experience can help with the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

```
.container{
  z-index: -1;    
}
```